# Collapsing a continuous gradient onto shape(text) only - in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, overlay, outline

As can be seen in the image provided I want this logo to have the 'water' gradient collapsed onto text only. Even if it likely means deleting the areas that fall outside the text after. [image]At a complete loss how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an **Opacity Mask**...

[image]

- Copy the text 
  (It doesn't matter if the text is "live text" or "outlines". The following steps are all the same.)
- Select the the gradient shape
- Click the `Make Mask` button on the **Transparency Panel** (Window > Transparency)
- Click the *mask thumbnail* on the **Transparency Panel** to edit the *mask*
- Choose `Edit > Paste in Front` (or back or in place) from the menu.
   This will paste the *copy* of the text you made earlier in the *exact same position* as it was copied from. You *can't* simply "paste". You need to use Front, back, or in Place to maintain positioning.
- Change the *color* of this newly pasted text to **white** so it's 100% visible on the *mask*.
- Click the *artwork thumbnail* on the **Transparency Panel** to go back to editing the artwork rather than the mask.

[image]

After clicking the *artwork thumbnail*, it's then a **good idea** to **Group** the text and this new masked gradient object in order to keep them aligned with each other.

Comment: Dude!  That worked like PERFECT --1st time!  Thank you so much! and I learned something too :)