# Subtract shape from text

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Created a shape over text, Opacity 30%. I'm trying to subtract the shape from text, so that the shape is only on the font. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What have you actually tried, or what has failed? It's kind of hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do here, but perhaps the Shape Builder tool could be used.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/143907/collapsing-a-continuous-gradient-onto-shapetext-only-in-illustrator

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your end game is here, but if you just want that 30% opacity white applied to your text then you can simply select both your text and the white shape and in the Transparency Panel click on the Make Mask button to create an Opacity Mask. The Clip button should be unchecked and the Invert Mask button should be checked.

Another option is to copy and Paste in Place the text- move it on top of the original text and the 30% shape then select the copied text and the 30% shape and make a clipping mask (Object> Clipping Mask> Make).